# help with simple query

Tags: php, sql

My config table:

```
name    | value
--------+------
version | 1.5.6
title   | test
```

How I try and get it:

```
$getCfg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
$config = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCfg);

echo $config['title'];
```

Equals to:

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\web\index.php on line 5
```

How would I get the value where the name is title?

The above doesn't work..well if I add WHERE title = 'test' and then echo $config['title']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$getCfg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
$config = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCfg)) {
  $config[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}

echo $config['title'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
echo $config['name'];
```

You need to index the result of `mysql_fetch_assoc` with the field name from the database which is "name".

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew is right. To avoid this problems in the future, print the contents of the config object:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($config);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I do to get the value where the name is title?
>
> The above doesn't work..well if I add WHERE title = 'test' and then echo $config['title']

```
SELECT * from config where name like 'title'
```

and you get that value with

```
echo $config['name']
```

You have to refer to the data by the column name, SQL doesn't automatically search for you, although that would be killer...